# Exercise 4.2.5 [HDP Book Vershynin]: Packing the balls into K

Tags: analysis, random-matrices

Suppose $T$ is a normed space. Prove that packing number $P(K,d,\epsilon)$ of $K \subset T$  is the largest number of closed disjoint balls with centers in $K$ and radii $\epsilon/2$. Show by example that the previous statement may be false for a general metric space $T$.

Def:(Packing numbers). A subset $\cal{N}$ of a metric space $(T,d)$ is $\epsilon$-separated if $d(x,y)>\epsilon$ for all distinct points $x,y\in \cal{N}$. The largest possible cardinality of an $\epsilon$-separated subset of a given set $K\subset T$ is called the packing number of $K$ and is denoted by $P(K,d,\epsilon)$

Proof: Suppose $P(K,d,\epsilon)= n$, so there are $n$ points in $K$ which are $\epsilon$-separated. Each of these $n$ points can be thought as a center of a $\epsilon/2$ radius ball. Then there are $n$ closed disjoint balls of radius $\epsilon/2$, that have their center in K. It remains to show that $n$ is largest number.
Assume that there are $n+1$ such $\epsilon/2$ radius closed disjoint balls that have centers in $K$, which implies that $K$ has $n+1$ $\epsilon$-separated points, which is contradictory to the fact that $K$ has a packing number $n$. Hence there can be at-most $n$ such balls.

Doubt: The above proof holds true for any metric space, which is not correct according to the question. Please help.

Comment: Hello @Bhaskar Mukhoty, welcome to MSE. Can you please add in the question (by editing it) what you have tried yourself? That way, it's easier for us to give you an appropriate answer for your problem. I also want to inform you that questions like "This is the problem, what's the answer?" are not always well-received on this site.

Comment: Hi @Ernie060, I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Cardinality may not correspond only to a finite number, I guess. I think your proof should strictly rely on bijections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $(T,d)$ be a finite metric space with two elements $T=\{a,b\}$ such that $d(a,b) =\epsilon$ and $K = T$ . Obviously $P(K,d,\epsilon)=1$, since the $\epsilon$-net can be only $\{a\}$ or $\{b\}$. However the number of disjoint closed balls with centers in $K$ and radii $\epsilon/2$ is 2 : one ball is $\{a\}$ and the second $\{b\}$ .

(I hope I'm not missing some subtility )

Answer (score 3):

Popescu Claudiu gave a great counter-example in general metric space.

Now I discussed why your original proof can only work in normed space: notice that the difference between normed space and metric space is that normed space must be a linear space, which means any $a,b \in T$ must have, say, $(a+b)/2 \in T$. But metric space does not need to, just as above counter-example shows.

Thus, for above example, if it is also a normed space then we must have $(a+b)/2 \in T$ and so the Ball $B(a,\epsilon/2)$ and $B(b, \epsilon/2)$ are not disjoint.

Comment: Interesting comment! I think if we wanted to a more general property than linearity, it could make sense, to mention [connectedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space). 

My impression is that the statement would hold for any connected metric space.